# I have a problem with buffer, is not grabbig all sums on my C program with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, while-loop, pthreads

So is something wrong with the data grabing from the buffer i have a a few producer threads and one consumer thread but the result of the sum of the data grabed from the buffer is aleays less than the actual computation

here is my code[comple code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JAW-5rbvOB7MCt2UYQ0WajD-ka1iHjKL)

here is my function that make the parcial sum, fist it computes the first part of the sum and then it grans another block to sum.Im losing my head here i think im doing it write but im a neewbie on these maybe im doing a big mistake, i cant understand why the buffer is not grabing all the info and extract it.

```
    void *do_work(void *es) 


   {


.....

        while (1) {

.... 
                for (i = start; i < end ; i++) {
                    pthread_mutex_lock (&sum_mutex);
                    while(items_buffer==NTHREADS){
                            pthread_cond_wait(&produzir,&pc);
                        }
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_calculo1);
                        mysum= a[i]*a[i];
                        buffer[items_buffer]=mysum;
                        items_buffer++;
                        //printf("o meu buffer tem %d items a soma parcial é de %d e o buffer tem %d\n",items_buffer,mysum,buffer[items_buffer]);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_calculo1);
                        pthread_cond_signal(&consumir);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock (&sum_mutex);

                }
        }
        saidas=saidas+1;
        //printf("tarefa %d de saída\n",tids);
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return NULL;
}
```

And here is the function that grabs the data from the buffer. im locking it so, i dont inderstand why is not grabing all the data. I cant detect the problem here.Maybe is some of my conditions or locking that are wrong.

```
void *do_sum(void *ts) 
{
int i;
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_geral);



    printf("Sou a thread somadora\n");
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_geral);

    while(items_buffer==0){
        pthread_cond_wait(&consumir,&pc);
    }

    while(saidas<NTHREADS){


        for(i=0;i<items_buffer;i++){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_soma);
            soma_buffer+=buffer[i];
            items_buffer--;
            //printf("o meu buffer ficou com %d items\n",items_buffer);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_soma);
        }
        pthread_cond_signal(&produzir);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_soma);
    for(i=0;i<items_buffer;i++){
            soma_buffer+=buffer[i];
            items_buffer--;
            //printf("o meu buffer ficou com %d items\n",items_buffer);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_soma);
    printf("Sou a thread somadora estou de saida\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
```

}

Am i doing something wrong?? I think im locking it well, the program runs fine, and every time the buffer is full the thread goes and empty it. and then gives space to other threads.Can some one give me an advice? Im losing my mind here.

here is my code[comple code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JAW-5rbvOB7MCt2UYQ0WajD-ka1iHjKL)

Comment: do not post links to code, rather copy/paste the code directly into your question.  Note: for code to post correctly, it has to be indented 4 spaces

Comment: regarding: `if(argc!=4)
 {
        printf("Utilização: ./mtss nt n nbloco\n");
        exit(1);
    }`  code should never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the expected number of parameters were entered

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: OT: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()` `calloc()` `realloc()`,  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `pthread_exit(NULL); return NULL;` the statement: `return NULL;` will never be executed because the statement: `pthread_exit( NULL );` already exited the thread. This problem (unreachable code) occurs in more than one place in the code

Comment: in general, it is good programming practice to limit the scope of variables.  For instance This code block: `for(z=0;z<ARRAYSIZE;z++){
  a[z]=z+1;
 }`  is using the variable `z` which has a scope of the whole `main()` function.  much better to write: `for( int z=0; z<ARRAYSIZE; z++ ){
  a[z]=z+1;
 }` so the scope of the variable is only the current code block and remove the declaration of `z` from early in the `main()` function.

Comment: the posted code only can use a single mutex and all the condition statements can be removed and the default for a thread is 'joinable' so no need to mess with an 'attr' to say that

Comment: regarding: `index_to_start=BLOCK_SIZE*NTHREADS;`  This results in`index_to_start` to index to past the end of the array of values `a[]`.  Also there is no check to assure the values entered by the user will actually work together.  (never trust the user to do the right thing) so the code needs to check each of the command line parameter values

Comment: OT:  regarding: `sum = (ARRAYSIZE*(ARRAYSIZE+1)*((2*ARRAYSIZE)+1))/6;`  Where did this calculation come from?

Comment: already resolve the problem, I will post it here, the bugs are normal because I'm working on the code, thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it’s a bit unclear what you’re trying to accomplish exactly, considering a sum from a buffer could be parallelized without complicated synchronization mechanisms by designating a pointer range for each thread to handle independently- I believe your bug is due to the fact that you are decrementing the size of the buffer in each loop ‘items_buffer--‘
This will cause you to miss the entire end of the array in the sum.

Edit: So that’s not the only problem
There are a number of issues here, I think you may need to review parallelization- *From what i can tell*, because of the way you use the condition variable alongside your mutex, your threads are not running concurrently. You are locking everything, executing a sum on one block, unlocking and then getting back in line to wait for the next finish signal. This is essentially a serial operation with the added overhead of synchronization mechanisms.

I suggest re-writing this procedure without locks; Divide your array into ranges (start and end pointers or integer indices). Each time you create a thread, make sure it has the correct range to work with.

In each thread, multiply your values and store them in a second buffer using the same index. Once the thread finishes all the multiplication, have it sum its own range from the second buffer, and add it into in a third buffer, the index of which should be the index of your thread (from your thread creation loop). Once you join all your threads, sum the final array and you have it. If you dont want a third array, just lock a mutex immediately before adding to an integer, then immediately unlock it.

The main reason you are using so many locks seems to be the use of static variables for buffers. You wouldn’t need to lock and clear your buffers if you use thread local variables.

Comment: so when should i decrement it? outside the loop?

Comment: so what the program is doing is, calculate a partila sum of a multiplication and put it on a buffer and then another thread goes sum that parcial sums from the buffer and empty the buffer

Comment: `for(i=0;i<items_buffer;i++){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_soma);
            soma_buffer+=buffer[i];
            items_buffer--;
            //printf("o meu buffer ficou com %d items\n",items_buffer);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_soma);
        }
        pthread_cond_signal(&produzir);` this is computing theparcial sum and put it in the buffer

Comment: `for(i=0;i<items_buffer;i++){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_soma);
            soma_buffer+=buffer[i];
            items_buffer--;
            //printf("o meu buffer ficou com %d items\n",items_buffer);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_soma);
        }
        pthread_cond_signal(&produzir);` and these is grabing the parcial sum from the buffer and clean the buffer

Comment: Why do you need to decrement the size? By decrementing the size each iteration, your loop will finish after N/2 iterations; Edit: Imagine there are 4 items. Loop 0, i=0; i<4. Next iteration, i=1;i<3. Next iteration, i=2;i<2 evaluates to false. You have only summed 2 of the 4 values.

Comment: I can see what you’re trying to do, you should be simply setting items_buffer to 0 after the loop is finished.

Comment: i will try that now

Comment: if i do that the result go up

Comment: is on main here you have all the code https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JAW-5rbvOB7MCt2UYQ0WajD-ka1iHjKL

Comment: How do ypu recomend that i take out the items from the buffer?? using a while? but how?

Comment: thanks all for the help problem solved, I will post the solution soon